# Numpy np.where multiple condition

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I need to work with multiple condition using numpy.

I'm trying this code that seem to work.

My question is: There is another alternative that can do the same job?

```
Mur=np.array([200,246,372])*pq.kN*pq.m
Mumax=np.array([1400,600,700])*pq.kN*pq.m
Mu=np.array([100,500,2000])*pq.kN*pq.m
Acreq=np.where(Mu<Mur,0,"zero")
Acreq=np.where(((Mur<Mu)&(Mu<Mumax)),45,Acreq)
Acreq=np.where(Mu>Mumax,60,Acreq)
Print(Acreq)
['0' '45' '60']
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide a sample data set and desired data set? In your code `pq.kN` and `pq.m` are not defined so it's hard to understand what is your input data set. PS is using Pandas module an option for you?

Comment: Hi Max, pq.kN and pq.m are units from the package "quantities". I´m trying to make an "if" and "else if" with the conditions:
If Mu<Mur ----> "x value"
If Mur<Mu<Mumax ----> "y value"
If Mu>Mumaz ----> "z value"

Comment: It can be done pretty easily in Pandas - would it be an option for you?

Comment: I don´t know what Pandas is. I´m a newbie in Python. But, yes, I have no problem trying this option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with this:

```
Mur    = np.array([200,246,372])*3*5
Mumax  = np.array([1400,600,700])*3*5
Mu     = np.array([100,500,2000])*3*5
Acreq  = np.where(Mu<Mur,0,"zero")
Acreq  = np.where((Mur<Mu)&(Mu<Mumax),45,Acreq)
Acreq  = np.where(Mu>Mumax,60,Acreq)

print(Acreq)

['0' '45' '60']
```

Try this:

```
conditions  = [Mu<Mur, (Mur<Mu)&(Mu<Mumax), Mu>Mumax ]
choices     = [ 0, 45, 60 ]
Acreq       = np.select(conditions, choices, default='zero')
print(Acreq)


['0' '45' '60']
```

This also works:

```
np.where((Mur<Mu)&(Mu<Mumax),45,np.where(Mu>Mumax,60,np.where(Mu<Mur,0,"zero")))
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank You!

Comment: Looks promising. How about with something like : `Mur,Mumax,Mu = [53,39,50]`?

Comment: If you use `Mur,Mumax,Mu = [53,39,50]` as the inputs and try out the original code and then your code, they give different results.

Comment: Mur,Mumax,Mu = [53,39,50] returns 60 in OP and both versions of the answered code.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Pandas's [pd.cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method:

generate random series of integers:

```
In [162]: import pandas as pd

In [163]: s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(-3,10, 10))

In [164]: s
Out[164]:
0    6
1   -3
2    6
3    6
4    7
5    7
6    3
7   -2
8    9
9    1
dtype: int32
```

categorize them:

```
In [165]: pd.cut(s, bins=[-np.inf, 2, 5, np.inf], labels=['0', '45', '60'])
Out[165]:
0    60
1     0
2    60
3    60
4    60
5    60
6    45
7     0
8    60
9     0
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [0 < 45 < 60]
```

Comment: Thanks! I´ll try this method