# Pandas - Selecting over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

**NB:** A question similar to this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916302/selecting-across-multiple-columns-with-python-pandas) but it doesn't exactly answer my question.

How do I subset a pandas dataframe, with many columns, based on certain large number of columns satisfying some boolean condition.

Right now, I'd have to do something like:

```
df[(df.column4 > a1) | (df.column23 < a2) | (df.column27 == a3) | ... 
    (df.column56 > a21) | (df.column72 < a22)]
```

Thanks

Comment: Well is there any sort of regularity to your conditions?

Comment: @Lagerbaer No. But supposing all the conditions were '>'. Is there a way for that even? I can't applymap a lambda function on columns and get only the required rows.

Comment: Well if you'd have a list of tuples (column name and condition) then you could iterate over that list and incrementally build up the condition to be used within the filter.

Comment: @Lagerbaer Right. But that's expensive.

Comment: If your condition was the same then you pass a list of cols and compare the entire thing: `df[list_of_cols] > some_val` gives you a mask you can then use this mask on the original df: `df[df[list_of_cols] > some_val]` note that it must be a real list: `df[['col1','col2'...]]` and not `df['col1','col2',...]` because the former is a list of column labels, the latter will be treated as a tuple and will raise a KeyError because it'll try to find a column named `'col1','col2'`

Comment: this may help, without data its hard to tell. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307268/numpy-np-where-multiple-condition/39309626#comment65952564_39309626

Comment: @EdChum This would return, if I'm not mistaken, a table of the same shape with NaN values where condn in not satisfied.

Comment: Well this is what your equivalent code asked for if you want something else then post actual data, code and desired output to avoid ambiguity

Comment: Actually you just need to wrap parentheses around the condition and call .any(): `df[(df[list_of_cols] > some_val).any()]` is equivalent to your code

Comment: @EdChum I'm afraid that's really not right either. I don't even have to run it to know it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to specify your conditions one way or another. You can create individual masks for each condition which you eventually reduce to a single one:

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import operator
import numpy as np

# Load a sample dataframe to play with
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# Define individual conditions as tuples
# ([column], [compare_function], [compare_value])
cond1 = ('sepal_length', operator.gt, 5)
cond2 = ('sepal_width', operator.lt, 2)
cond3 = ('species', operator.eq, 'virginica')
conditions = [cond1, cond2, cond3]

# Apply those conditions on the df, creating a list of 3 masks
masks = [fn(df[var], val) for var, fn, val in conditions]
# Reduce those 3 masks to one using logical OR
mask = np.logical_or.reduce(masks)

result = df.ix[mask]
```

When we compare this with the "hand-made" selection, we see they're the same:

```
result_manual = df[(df.sepal_length>5) | (df.sepal_width<2) | (df.species == 'virginica')]
result_manual.equals(result) # == True
```

Comment: I learnt a couple of things from this answer: using reduce to create masks. Don't know why I never thought of that. Thanks.