# How to have list's elements as a condition in np.where()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to create a new column based on the values of another column where there are certain conditions to be evaluated for the values assigned in the new column.

I read a few questions and answers ([Numpy np.where multiple condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307268/numpy-np-where-multiple-condition)) involving `np.where()` but was unable to deduce the best(efficient) Pythonic way.

Sample dataframe is:

```
      period
0      JAN16 
1  YTD JAN16
```

I want to assign values to column `period_type` on the following condition:
if period starts with x (where x is any element of a list -> ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']), then period_type = 'month', else, period_type = period.split(0)

I would like the dataframe to be:

```
      period period_type
0      JAN16       month
1      JAN16       YTD
```

I am unable to apply any logic in my code whatsoever:

```
df.loc[df['c1'] == 'Value', 'c2'] = 10
```

Or:

```
df['c2'] = np.where(df.c1 == 8,'X',df.c3)
```

Comment: it's bad form to reform your question when 4 people have answered the original question

Comment: apologies, i made a comment on each of them btw

Comment: Basically it looks like you want to generate a new column and then normalise your first column, is that correct?

Comment: yes @EdChum, you are correct!

Comment: I'd post a new question about how to normalise the first column. If you'd updated your question early enough then I wouldn't have too much of an issue but you updated it several times and then 4 people answered the original question. Now you're asking all of us to take into consideration your additional requirement which is poor form. So accept an answer, post a new question with just that requirement

Comment: I updated my question just once, right within 5 mins. I understand efforts being wasted. However, I hope one would realise that to err is human and would let go of this. 
As for the other question, I have got an answer and I am accepting one right away. Downvoting my question wasn't helpful either, your explanation was! Thanks again for answering the question and for teaching me the right way to ask questions. :)

Comment: I agree with @EdChum.

Comment: @Wen-Ben okay sir, punishment received. got many downvotes and lesson learned. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is using [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) to check which rows do start with any of the values in the list (it also accepts a tuple of strings), and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to set the rows in the new column to `month` or the actual row value splitted and taking the first value:

```
l = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 
     'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']

m = df.period.str.startswith(tuple(l))
df['period_type'] = np.where(m, 'month', df.period.str.split().str[0])
df.loc[~m, 'period'] = df.loc[~m, 'period'].str.split().str[1]

   period   period_type
0  JAN16       month
1  JAN16         YTD
```

Comment: Could you re-look at the question? I just updated my question, the expected output. Thanks

Comment: The expected output is the same right? @AviralSrivastava

Comment: no, i have updated the `expected output` in my question. It is now JAN16 as a month for `YTD JAN16` where period is `YTD`. Hence, earlier it was `YTD JAN16` <-.> `YTD` but now it is `JAN16` <-> `YTD`, `FEB16`<->`L3M`. I hope you got me? I am removing the type from the period's value as well

Answer (score 7):

IIUC `isin` with `str` slice

```
np.where(df.period.str[:3].isin(l),'month',df.period.str.split(' ').str[0])
Out[1162]: array(['month', 'YTD'], dtype=object)

df['period_type'] = np.where(df.period.str[:3].isin(l),'month',df.period.str.split(' ').str[0])
```

Comment: Could you re-look at the question? I just updated my question, the expected output. Thanks

Comment: @AviralSrivastava adding `df.period=df.period.str.splir(' ').str[-1]` after above

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to use `str.contains` and pass a regex pattern:

```
In[22]:
df['period_type'] = np.where(df['period'].str.contains('^(' + '|'.join(months) + ')') , 'month', df['period'].str.split().str[0])
df


Out[22]: 
      period period_type
0      JAN16       month
1  YTD JAN16         YTD
2  L3M FEB19         L3M
```

Here `months` is your months list, we construct a regex pattern where `'^'` means begins with, then we join all the columns with `'|'` to say any begin with any of these patterns, we can then pass this to `np.where` to construct the new column.

The regex pattern generated is:

```
In[23]:
'^(' + '|'.join(months) + ')'
Out[23]: '^(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)'
```

Comment: The only catch is, default value cannot be `YTD`. It has to be the first element of the list l(say) where l is the list created by period.split().

Comment: @anky_91 don't know, maybe

Comment: Could you re-look at the question? I just updated my question, the expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you create months as`tuple`, you could get it as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'period' : ['JAN16', 'YTD JAN16', 'FEB18', 'YEAR DEC']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
months = ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC')
df['period_type'] = np.where(df['period'].str.startswith(months), 'month', df['period'].str.split().str[0] )
df['period'] = np.where(df['period_type'] == 'month', df['period'], df['period'].str.split().str[1] )
print(df)
```

Comment: Could you re-look at the question? I just updated my question, the expected output. Thanks

Comment: And isn't your `months` a tuple?

Comment: thanks, could you also take another look at the question?

Comment: You could add another line like `df['period'] = np.where(df['period_type'] == 'month', df['period'], df['period'].str.split().str[1] )`